# find and append new files in tarball

Tags: solaris, ksh

I got a list of files after find command.Now,it is required to remove the existing archive file from and append the files after command.

> find /u01/apps/ ( -name '*.log0*' -o -name '*.out0*' ) -atime +30

returns a list of .out and .log files. Now, it is required to delete existing files in a tarball(manually created) and append the new files.

How can it be done?

I googled but couldnt find the appropriate result according to this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind using find command twice? The first one to remove files and then another one to add them?
This could help (maybe you should make some adjustments):

```
find /u01/apps/ ( -name '.log0' -o -name '.out0' ) -atime +30 -printf %P\\n | xargs tar -f foobar.tar --delete
```

And then:

```
find /u01/apps/ ( -name '.log0' -o -name '.out0' ) -atime +30 -printf %P\\n | xargs tar -f foobar.tar -r
```

Comment: Thanks cesarrse,apologies, i should have mentioned it before, am going to add it to crontab, so printf woulodnot br usefull and moreover my ksh doesn't have --delete option for tar :(

Comment: Hmm... You could try to extract all files to a temp directory, replace the old ones with their new versions and, at last, compact everything again. A neither elegant nor compact solution, but it ought work.